# Continuity of an increasing function at zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function with $f(y_n)-f(x_n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, where $x_n<0<y_n$ $\forall n\ge1$. Then, is $f$ continuous at zero?

I think yes, but am unable to precisely prove. If the sequence were given to be monotone, then probably the proof would have been easier with the definition of continuity, but it is not the case. Any hints? Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $n$ such that $f(y_n)-f(x_n) <\epsilon$ and $x_n <0 <y_n$. Suppose $x_n < x\leq 0 \leq y <y_n$. Then $f(y)-f(x)\leq f(y_n)-f(x_n) <\epsilon $ by monotonicity of $f$. If you take $\delta $ to be $\min \{y_n, -x_n\}$  then $|u-0| < \delta$ implies $|f(u)-f(0)| <\epsilon$. Can you verify this? Hint: in our estimates you can take $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: why can we take $x=0$ or $y=0$?

Comment: By monotonicity.